# Android Things console will be turned down for all existing projects on January 5, 2022

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things, android-things-console

*Android Things* posted this:

> The Android Things console will stop supporting new projects on January 5, 2021, and will be turned down for all existing projects on January 5, 2022."

We are using currently *Raspberry Pi 3B* with *Android Things* OS.

My question is: will we be able to use existing OS running in *Raspberry Pi* even after turning down *Android Things* console?

Answer (score 1):

> Will we be able to use existing OS running in Raspberry Pi even after turning down Android Thing console?

Since Android Thing Console does not affect the OS that is running on a hardware, I believe you'll be able to.

Answer (score 1):

Once the console is turned down, you will not be able to access the factory images or push updates to your devices. You will need to download your latest factory images before then and flash devices manually. This will not affect devices already running and Android Things image.

See the [FAQ page](https://developer.android.com/things/faq) for more details.